# Input Tag Helper issue in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In ASP.NET view, shown below, I'm getting the error that is specific to line `<input asp-for="StateName" />`
**Error**: 
`'List<GrantsViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'StateName'`

**NOTE**: View is supposed to display different State Names in an HTML table column.

**Controller**:

```
public class DbTestController : Controller
    {
        private MyProjContext _context;

        public DbTestController(MyProjContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

    public IActionResult GrantNumbers()
    {
        var qryVM = from s in _context.StateNames
               join g in _context.AnnualGrants on s.StateNumber equals g.StateNumber into sg
               from r in sg.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new GrantsViewModel() { StateNumber = s.StateNumber,StateName= s.State, GrantNo= (r == null ? String.Empty : r.GrantNo), FiscalYear = (r == null ? 1900 : r.FiscalYear) };

       return View(qryVM.ToList());
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**:

```
public class GrantsViewModel
    {
        public int GrantNo_Id { get; set; }
        public string StateNumber { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public string GrantNo { get; set; }
        public int FiscalYear { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**:

```
@model List<MyProjet.Models.GrantsViewModel>

<form asp-controller="DbTest" asp-action="GrantNumbers" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().StateName)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().GrantNo)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="StateName" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GrantNo)
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Why are you using asp-helpers over razor if you're working with .net mvc?

Comment: You have a form, but you are loading information from a database. If you only want to display information, then you shouldn't have a form. If you are wanting to gather new data via a form, then your form should be separate from your loaded data.

Comment: @Jecoms 1. I'm trying to use new MVC6 feature [HTML Tag Helpers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html), in particular [input tag helper](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/13/mvc6-input-tag-helper-deep-dive.aspx) 2. This is an app where customer wants to have form with pre-loaded data (HttpGet) and have user be able to modify that data (hence input tag) then save the data (hence posting the form back in HttpPost ).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StateName)
```

In this line you are trying to access the property `StateName` from the object referenced by `model`. Except model references an object of type `List<T>`, which does not have a property StateName.

To access StateName, you need to provide which element of the list you are accessing, such as the following (assuming you don't need to iterate, since you are just getting the column titles).

```
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].StateName)
```

To reference the element correctly in the asp-for helper, use

```
<input asp-for="@item.StateName" />
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error in the `<th>..<\th>`. I've made the correction in the view above. But the error I've posted in the post is in the `<input asp-for="StateName" />` that is using `asp-for` attribute in  [Helper tag](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/13/mvc6-input-tag-helper-deep-dive.aspx).

Comment: You're running into the same issue. The asp-for helper tag is looking for a property on your model, and List doesn't have StateName.

Comment: So, how do I change `<input asp-for="StateName" />`? The `<input asp-for="model[0].StateName" />` does not work.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you want those to target the item you have in the foreach loop, not just the first item.
In which case, change it to `<input asp-for="@item.StateName" />`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use FirstOrDefault() when referencing names of properties. This will still be able to get the display names using reflection even if your IEnumerable/List Model is empty.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().StateName)
```

Instead of the StateName asp-tag, here is the Razor Helper for an input:

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.StateName)
```

I'm a bit confused as to why you have this table in a form if you're wanting to just display your list of information. If you clarify, I can better answer based on your intent.

If you just want this data displayed, then use a DisplayFor() like you did for GrantNo column:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StateName)
```